# Tweepy and streaming

Tags: django, twitter, tweepy

im playing with django and tweepy, and im really don't know how i can use [this example](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2605-how-to-capture-tweets-in-real-time-with-twitters-streaming-api/) about Streaming with django

how i can pass the streaming data to my context?

Comment: What do you mean by "streaming"? You send request to Django and get the response, no "streaming" is possible here in simple way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you investigate using websockets for this type of thing, run the linked tweet streaming script as a separate service using django-websocket (or something similar) and push the content back to the open html5 websocket.